# How can I use c++ file in thunderbird add-on?

Tags: c++, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

How can I use c++ file in thunderbird add-on? I am developing one add-on in thunderbird so, I want to execute below function in C++, can anyone know how can I include c++ file in thunderbird and execute below function?

```
gtk_clipboard_wait_for_image
```

Comment: Writing a plug-in, and compiling it? Seriously, what is your question?

Comment: Ya, I am writing plugin which is made in .js and xul but now, I want to execute above c++ function also how can I do it?

Comment: Your question is much to broad to fit a Q&A format. You appear to not have *any* experience with C++ programming, which would make any answer ridiculously long, effectively ending up as a "how to C++" tutorial plus a chapter added for the thunderbird part. Since C++ is a very much non-trivial language, the best advice anyone could give is probably: "Read a C++ book first, then come back with any *specific* question you might still have".